# notifyDataSetChanged() caused other recyclerview scroll to reset

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling, recyclerview-layout

I have a very weird problem. I have 2 recyclerviews (recyclerview #1 with horizontal scrolling and recyclerview #2). When I called `notifyDataSetChanged()` from adapter for recyclerview #2, it resets scrolling in recyclerview #1.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="8dp">
        <TextView android:text="Selected: "
                  style="@style/ProdGroupLabel" />
        <TextView android:text="@{prod.name}"
                  android:maxEms="12"
                  style="@style/ProdGroupLabel" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonedit"
                android:text="Edit"
                android:visibility="@{menu.hasOptions ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"
                style="@style/ProdGroupButtonEdit"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/recyclerview2"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:visibility="@{menu.hasOptions ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I initialized my adapter

```
recyclerview1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
recyclerview1.addItemDecoration(new SpaceItemDecoration(context, R.dimen.horz_spacing));
recyclerview1.setAdapter(productRecyclerAdapter);
recyclerview1.setHasFixedSize(true);

recyclerview2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
recyclerview2.setAdapter(productOptionRecyclerAdapter);
recyclerview2.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

When the user select the product, it will update items of  `productOptionRecyclerAdapter` to reflect the available options for that product. In `productOptionRecyclerAdapter` when the source has changed, I called `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

The problem is, every time `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called in `productOptionRecyclerAdapter`, it scrolls `recyclerview1` to position (0,0). But `recyclerview1` has nothing to do with `productOptionRecyclerAdapter`. (And yes, if I commented out `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `productOptionRecyclerAdapter`, then it doesn't reset the scrollbar.)

Any idea why?

Comment: try using diffUtils in your adapter to update your recycler view items, doing notifyDataSetchanged every time is not a good practice.

Comment: I just figured it out, the problem is that every time the layout is changed, it reset the scrolling. Any idea on how to prevent scroll to be reset? I've post another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274599/onlayout-changed-causes-recyclerview-horizontal-scroll-to-reset