# onLayout changed causes RecyclerView horizontal scroll to reset

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

When the text is changed, the layout refreshed and the scrolling in the recyclerview is resets to position 0, 0.

Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="132dp"
                                            android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="8dp">
        <TextView android:text="@{prod.name}"
                  android:maxEms="12"
                  style="@style/ProdGroupLabel" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonedit"
                android:text="Edit"
                android:visibility="@{prod.hasOptions ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"
                style="@style/ProdGroupButtonEdit"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, when the product name has changed, it will appear in the text view `<TextView android:text="@{prod.name}"`. This will force the `recyclerview1` to reset its scroll position to 0,0.

Any idea on how to prevent the scrolling and preserve the original scrolling?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of last visible position of layout manager you must be using before setting text

```
int position =  manager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
```

Then u can do like this

```
rv.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(poaition)
```

There is also

> **findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition** you can make use of.

Comment: I tried to capture it before the text is changed and restore the layout once it has been changed calling `((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerview1.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPosition(lastFirstVisiblePosition);` but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Check the returned value of position, is it returning value properly.

Comment: Yep, it is returning a correct position. In my case is 6.

Comment: Ok, try to do inside handler.postDelay using 500 milliseconds and see if it's working.

Comment: It sort of work, but it doesn't retain the position. It is moving side to side unreliably :(

Comment: Get the position outside handler and do the scrolling inside handler. Also u can try to use smoothScrollToPosition method.

Comment: The position I get is outside the handler. The position is correct. I did tried smoothScrollToPosition. The problem is, when I select the item, it is in the middle, but then it get scroll to the left (or right). Even though it jumps to visible location, it jumps all over the place. Smooth scrolling doesn't help :(

Comment: Try to use findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition to get the position, don't know more sorry :(

Comment: still doesn't work :( Is there away to prevent the scrolling?